# Kubernetes pod network hang up

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running a Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud (version 
1.13.7-gke.24). The same code is running on the machine for more than 3 months without any problems. Today I found that one of the pods became disconnected from the network for more than 24 hours.

First I checked if the pod had internet connectivity, normally it has. I used `curl` to query some well-known internet websites - all of them were out of reach. The same thing happened when I tried to run `apt-get update` or `apt-get upgrade`.

Second, I check for logs of my applications and I found exceptions like this:

```
Unable to log to provider GoogleStackdriverLogProvider, ex: Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Connect Failed")
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`2.<<WithRetry>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at ***.LogService.Providers.GoogleStackdriverLogProvider.WriteAsync(IEnumerable`1 entries) in LogService/Providers/GoogleStackdriverLogProvider.cs:line 71
```

Those logs are coming from code I running that send new logs to Google Stackdriver. Note that those log a stored in the same datacenter - no need internet to send them out and still the application couldn't reach the destination.

Last, this is a strange one, the connectivity to the queue system was keep running. Unfortunately, the application was continued to download new messages from the queue but all of them was ended with failure because of the network connectivity.

Summary:

```
Internet connectivity - NO
VPC connectivity - YES
GCP services connectivity - YES
```

Other notes:

- I was able to `ssh` into the problematic pod.
- Restarting the pod fixed the issue.
- It never happened before. I'm running this deployment for more than a year.
- The problematic pod was 4 and a half days old when I was killing it.
- Only one pod was affected by this problem. All other (100+ pods) was running without any problem.

What to do in order to prevent this problem in the further?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a transient issue, possibly due to a failure with the virtual interface created for the pod. These types of failure are rare and hard to prevent. However, you can build your deployment to be more resilient using [livenessProbes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes) so that this type of error will cause the container to fail and be recreated.

Unfortunately, if restating the container is not enough, the pod will go into crashLoopBackOff state. You could set up alerts that notify you if pod's do go into this state to trigger pod deletion.

Though it may not be possible to prevent, you can automate its recovery

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. Sounds like `livenessProbes` can be a "quick and dirty" solution for this problem. The question is how to verify that the pod has internet and service connections? `Ping` some places on the internet may be dangerous for the production environment, no?

Comment: Easiest way to test for internet would be a curl Google.com, but that won't be the probe. Your prone needs to check your pod for functionality which relies on internet. The probe depends on how your code works and what it does.